# Is the existence of the lamb implied?

Tags: exodus, numbers, passover

In Exodus 12:8 (NASB)

> They shall eat the flesh that same night, roasted with fire, and they shall eat it with unleavened bread and bitter herbs.

we can read of a roasted lamb that goes together with the unleavened bread and bitter herbs. Then, in Numbers 9:11-12 (NASB)

> 11 In the second month on the fourteenth day at twilight, they shall celebrate it; they shall eat it with unleavened bread and bitter herbs. 12 They shall not leave any of it until morning, nor break a bone of it; they shall celebrate it in accordance with the whole statute of the Passover.

Does Numbers 9:11-12 assume the existence of the roasted lamb?

Comment: I struggle to understand the motivation for this question.  Why was the lamb not present?

Comment: @Dottard just for clarification since the word "lamb" doesn't exist in that passage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are to eat [the lamb],
יֹאכְלֻֽהוּ׃ (yō·ḵə·lu·hū)
Verb - Qal - Imperfect - third person masculine plural | third person masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 398: To eat

Does Numbers 9:11-12 assume the existence of the roasted lamb?

Yes, it is implied by the grammar and the context.

> 12 They shall not leave any of it until morning, nor break a **bone** of it;

Exodus 12:46

> "It must be eaten inside the house; take none of the meat outside the house. Do not break any of the **bones**.